# Recreating the Liferay jsessionId in a custom theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I have created links in my theme. Unfortunately those links need to contain something like this : "http://localhost:8080/test:jsessionid=ABCDEFG" .

I was able to do this in a journal article using this code:

```
;jsessionid=$request.get('portlet-session-id')
```

but I am not able to do the same thing in my theme.

Can anyone help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get jsessionid in theme by using `$request.getRequestedSessionId()`.